# Photoshop wrong displaying Roboto font style

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I used the Roboto font for my projects in Photoshop. 
I donwloaded from here http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html . 
I unistalled the old Roboto and installed the new version of Roboto font which you can see here http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-roboto-noto 
With this new version Roboto Regular is the same as Roboto Black. I mean it's exactly the same. Is this a Font bug or Photoshop bug or maybe Windows 8 installed the font wrong ?

Other Roboto Styles are displayed as expected.

Photoshop version 2014.2.1

Comment: Did you try clearing the font cache? http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/troubleshoot-fonts-photoshop-cs5.html#id_9946

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. I think it was a Windows issue. 
I tried to remove and reinstall all Roboto fonts but after that Photoshop started to show an error every time I try to open a file with Roboto font in it: `Selected font failed during last operation. If problem persists, please disable the font.`  
I removed all Roboto fonts. 
I found this link from Adobe 
http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/troubleshoot-fonts-photoshop-cs5.html 
But when I tried to delete the system font cache, Windows said it was used by some program so I deleted those files in `Safe mode` than installed all Roboto fonts. Now it works perfect with all Roboto styles.